# Put text in textbox

Tags: html, css, textbox

Is there a way to put text in a textbox but also allow the user to type something.  I would like to write "username:" inside the box and allow the user to type after the colon.  I can do this the hard way by creating a div right next to a textbox and make it look like they are one container, but I was wondering if there was an easier way?  Thanks

EDIT: I don't want to text to disappear.  I just want to user to be able to continue typing

EDIT 2: the reason you cant put a value in the textbox is because its  a form.  when the user types a username next to the value it will submit together

Comment: Please use better tags in future questions.

Comment: @user: so now I'm confused; why not just pre-populate the input or use an adjacent span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<div>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{border:1px solid gray;}
label{font-family:arial; font-size:.8em;}
input{border:none;}
input:focus{outline:none;}
```

Basically, created a containing `div` and placed a `label` and `input` in that `div`.  `label` is the words that stay in the field.  `input` has the `border` removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/rZmFx/

Fyi... you may need to increase the size of the `input`, depending on how many characters you want to accept.

Answer (score 9):

HTML5 has a [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute you can now use:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username" />
```

People have also [created javascript functions](http://www.beyondstandards.com/archives/input-placeholders/) that mimic this functionality.

There's also a [jQuery placeholder](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder) plugin which does the same, if you'd like to go that route.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with using standard HTML? You don't say that you need it to disappear...

```
<input type="text" value="username: " />
```

If you need it to disappear, use a placeholder attribute and a jQuery plugin as a fallback (for the browsers that don't support it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Category"/>
```

Maybe that can help you. If you want the textbox for only read you can put the property `readonly = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

You could call this javascript function once the page is loaded:

```
function add(text){
    var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("Mytextbox");
    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, you can use the placeholder attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp