# C# TextBox with persistent text

Tags: c#, textbox, userform

For a game I am trying to make a textbox that will have a text similar to "0 / 100". I would like that text to:

1. Always persist, i.e. clicking the textbox to NOT make the text disappear. I know I can create event handlers for OnFocus/LoseFocus, but that still makes the text disappear.
2. The user be able to only enter values in the left portion of the text. I.e. I would like the user to only modify the "XXX" portion in this example: "XXX / 100".

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619299/put-text-in-textbox) question, but it is for CSS.

Also, I am aware I *could* make something *look* like what I want, but I would prefer to do that only if what I want can't be achieved with only a textbox.

Comment: Have you had a look at the MaskedTextBox?

Comment: Just put a label with "/ 100" to the right of the TextBox.

Comment: @BerndLinde, I haven't heard about that before, I will look into it now. LarsTech, please read again the last paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RichTextBox control to accomplish that:

```
var rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
rtb.Location = new Point(16, 16);
rtb.Size = new Size(96, 23);
rtb.Multiline = false;
rtb.Text = " / 100";
rtb.SelectAll();
rtb.SelectionProtected = true;
rtb.Select(0, 0);      
rtb.KeyPress += rtb_KeyPress;
this.Controls.Add(rtb);

void rtb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
  if (rtb.SelectionStart == rtb.TextLength) {
    e.Handled = true;
  } else if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) {
    e.Handled = true;
  } else if (rtb.TextLength == 9) {
    if (rtb.SelectionLength > 0) {
      if (rtb.SelectionStart > 3) {
        e.Handled = true;
      }
    } else {
      e.Handled = true;
    }
  } else if (rtb.SelectionStart == 0 && rtb.SelectionLength == 0) {
    rtb.SelectionProtected = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Since I haven't heard about RichTextBoxes before, am I right in assuming your code checks what text is selected and if it is more than the left part - selects the left part only? Also, can RichTextBoxes be given a transparent background if defined as custom controls, like TextBoxes can?

Comment: @mathgenius I tried to accommodate for any scenario I can think of.  Try the code I posted and try to break it.  As far as transparent backgrounds go, no idea.  TextBox and RichTextBox both inherit from TextBoxBase, so if something works in TextBox, it should work for the RichTextBox.  But both of those controls are old-old-school.

Comment: Thanks, I'd mark your question as correct, but I am still trying to figure out where exactly to place the code or what topic to research on the matter.

Comment: @mathgenius The form's constructor is probably the best place to put it.  Change the location and size to suit your needs.  You can create this with the designer, but the SelectionProtected related stuff would still have to run from code.